# How to set `max_prepared_stmt_count` **permanently** on mysql server?

Tags: mysql, configuration

I need to increase `max_prepared_stmt_count`, and I can do that easily by running

```
set global max_prepared_stmt_count=50000;
```

The problem, though, is that number gets reset to the default everytime after a reboot. I've tried adding in lines like

```
max_prepared_stmt_count=50000;
```

into various config files, but they spit out the same error:

```
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'max_prepared_stmt_count=50000'
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In what conf files do you set it and what MySQL version do you use? It should be set in /etc/my.cnf

Comment: Make sure you add the setting to the `[mysqld]` section. And don't add the semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add it in `/etc/my.cnf` on this way:

```
[mysqld]
max_prepared_stmt_count = 50000
```

Comment: I don't have that file. Should I create it? I do have `/etc/mysq/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`.

Comment: edit it in `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` (if this is the config of your mysql instance)

Comment: Didn't work. Still shows default variable like 16382 when I type `show variables like 'max_prepared_stmt_count';`

Comment: @Taylor, did you restart mysql after config file change?

Comment: I did not. woops. let me check that

Comment: Yay, works. I typed `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` and checked. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

For people running MySQL on [AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/), you can create your own Parameter Group and set the value of `max_prepared_stmt_count` there:

1. AWS Console -> [RDS](https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home)
2. RDS -> [Parameter Groups](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?region=us-west-2#parameter-groups:)
3. Create Parameter Group
4. Give it a name
5. Back to [Parameter Groups](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?region=us-west-2#parameter-groups:), select the group you created
6. In the search bar at the top, type `max_prepared_stmt_count`
7. Click the checkbox on the left to select the row
8. Click Edit Parameter in the top right corner
9. Update the value in the row
10. Click Save Changes in the top right corner